# Locally Lipschitz at a point and around a point.

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I am confronted with 2 definitions
Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $f:A\to \mathbb R^m$.

$f$ is said to be locally Lipschitz at a point $c \in A$ if 
$$
(\exists \delta>0)(\exists L \ge 0)(\forall x \in A)\\ \Vert x-c\Vert<\delta \implies \Vert f(x)-f(c)\Vert\le L\Vert x-c\Vert
$$
 and $f$ is said to be locally Lipscihtz around a point $c\in A$ if $$
(\exists \delta>0)(\exists L \ge 0)(\forall x,y \in K(c,\delta))\\ \Vert f(x)-f(y)\Vert\le L\Vert x-y\Vert
$$
obviously the second definition asks for more and every locally Lipschitz function around a point is also locally Lipschitz in a point, but I am trying to prove that the opposite isn't true and have been failing for a while

the only thing the first definition gives is 
$$\Vert f(x)-f(y)\Vert \le L (\Vert x-c\Vert + ||y-c||)$$

edit: $K(c,\delta)$ is an open ball around $c$ with a radius $\delta$

Comment: If you're willing to give up differentiability, and even continuity, at points away from $c,$ then consider $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ defined by $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational. It is easy to see that $f$ is locally Lipschitz at $x=0$ $(L = 1$ works) and $f$ is not Lipschitz in any neighborhood of $x=0.$ Note that the graph is just the graph of $y = |x|$ with all points having an irrational first coordinate moved down to the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{2}\sin(1/x^{2})$ for $x\ne 0$, $f(0)=0$, we have $f'(0)=0$, so it is locally Lipschitz at $0$, but $f'(x)$ is unbounded around $0$, so it is not locally Lipschitz around $0$.

Comment: how is $f'$ not bounded around 0? Isnt $f'(x)=2sin(1/x)-cos(1/x)$ for $x \not= 0$ and $f'(0)=0$?. Isnt that bounded by 2?

Comment: What about now?

Comment: Now it becomes $f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x^{2})-(2/x)\cos(1/x^{2})$ for $x\ne 0$.